# JavaScript: Divide database date into Overdue, Today and tomorrow

Tags: javascript, sorting, date

I have created basic React todo list and save it to my database. I set `dueDatetime` query where it sets the time. I want to query that time in one objects with multiple arrays. like this:

```
  {
      “overdue”: [],
       “today”: [],
       “tomorrow”: [],
       rest of the upcoming dates
    }
```

Based on dates I want to display tasks number. I really don't know where to start. I don't want to use any package for that. I will be really glad if someone help me out. I share my code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/date-nf765?file=/src/App.js).

**This is my frontend code. **`PS: Basically I did not anything. because i don't know where to start`****

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import date from "./Date.json";
import styled from "styled-components";

export default function App() {
  const signledate = date?.data?.map((i) => {
    return new Date(i.dueDatetime);
  });
  // console.log(signledate);

  const datadate = date?.data?.slice(0, 1)?.map((i) => {
    return i.dueDatetime;
  });
  console.log(signledate);
  console.log(new Date());
  return (
    <Container>
      <Card>
        <Text>You have 10 overdue</Text>
      </Card>
      <Card>
        <Text>Today you have 6 tasks</Text>
      </Card>
      <Card>
        <Text>Tomorrow you have 20 tasks</Text>
      </Card>
      <Card>
        <Text>Jan 23 5 task </Text>
      </Card>
      <Card>
        <Text>Jan 24 2 task </Text>
      </Card>
    </Container>
  );
}

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
`;

const Card = styled.div`
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
`;

const Text = styled.text`
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 20px;
`;
```

**This is my dymmydata in json**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-01-21T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-03-15T14:30:22.149836Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": "any weekday",
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-01-22T16:30:11.007867Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-01-23T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-01-25T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-04-15T14:30:22.149836Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": "any weekday",
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-04-15T16:30:11.007867Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-04-26T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-01-22T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-05-15T14:30:22.149836Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": "any weekday",
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-05-15T16:30:11.007867Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-05-24T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-02-07T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-01-22T16:30:11.007867Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-06-17T14:30:22.149836Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": "any weekday",
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-01-21T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-07-05T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-07-15T14:30:22.149836Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": "any weekday",
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-07-15T16:30:11.007867Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-07-19T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-08-02T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-08-15T14:30:22.149836Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": "any weekday",
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-01-22T16:30:11.007867Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-08-16T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-08-30T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-09-13T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-09-15T16:30:11.007867Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-09-16T14:30:22.149836Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": "any weekday",
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-01-23T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-01-21T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-10-15T14:30:22.149836Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": "any weekday",
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-10-15T16:30:11.007867Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-10-25T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-11-08T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-01-22T14:30:22.149836Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": "any weekday",
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-11-15T16:30:11.007867Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-11-22T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-12-06T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-12-15T16:30:11.007867Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-12-16T14:30:22.149836Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": "any weekday",
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-12-20T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2020-01-03T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2020-01-15T14:30:22.149836Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": "any weekday",
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2020-01-15T16:30:11.007867Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2020-01-17T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2020-01-31T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2020-02-14T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2020-02-15T16:30:11.007867Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2020-02-17T14:30:22.149836Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": "any weekday",
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-01-22T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2020-03-13T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2020-03-14T22:28:14Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2020-03-15T16:30:11.007867Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2020-03-16T14:30:22.149836Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": "any weekday",
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-01-27T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-01-23T14:30:22.149836Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": "any weekday",
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need 3 filters:

```js
const oneDay = 24 * 3600 * 1000; // we do not take into account Daylight-savings
let today = new Date();
today.setHours(0);
today.setMinutes(0);
today.setSeconds(0);
today.setMilliseconds(0);
today = today.getTime();

const tasks = {
  overdue: dummydata.data.filter(task => (new Date(task.dueDatetime)).getTime() < today),
  today: dummydata.data.filter(task => 
  { 
    const due = (new Date(task.dueDatetime)).getTime();
    return due >= today && due < today + oneDay;
  }),
  tomorrow: dummydata.data.filter(task => 
  {
    const due = (new Date(task.dueDatetime)).getTime();
    return due >= today + oneDay && due < today + oneDay * 2;
  }),
  rest: dummydata.data.filter(task => (new Date(task.dueDatetime)).getTime() >= today + oneDay * 2),
};
```

You can speedup the filtration if you cycle only once through the dummydata (e.g. with `forEach`) - and push the task to the corresponding group depending on its `dueDatetime`:

```js
  const today = new Date().toISOString().substr(0,10);    
  let tomorrow = new Date();
  tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
  tomorrow = tomorrow.toISOString().substr(0,10);
  const overdueTasks = [], todayTasks = [], tomorrowTasks = [], restTasks = [];

  date.data.forEach(task =>
    {
      const stamp = new Date(task.dueDatetime).toISOString().substr(0,10);
      if(stamp < today) overdueTasks.push(task);
      else if(stamp === today) todayTasks.push(task);
      else if(stamp === tomorrow) tomorrowTasks.push(task);
      else restTasks.push(task);
    });
```

Comment: when i print out it does not display today's task. https://codesandbox.io/s/date-nf765?file=/src/App.js

Comment: This uses "now" as the current date, so timestamps that are the same day but earlier time will be classed as "overdue" when they should probably be "today". It adds one day by adding only 8.64e4 ms when there are 8.64e7 ms in 24 hours. Adding a day using milliseconds is not a good idea where daylight saving is observed.

Comment: I fixed the bug - please check again.

Comment: @IVOGELOV You mentioned `const oneDay = 24 * 3600 * 1000; // we do not take into account Daylight-savings.`  but I live in Europe. And we follow daylight saving. Is there any way I can do the daylight saving with your code. I used one package called `[Day.js](https://day.js.org/en/)`. But don't know how to use the logic.

Comment: I also live in Europe. The second example (`forEach` cycle) does not use the `oneDay` constant - is it giving wrong results for you?

Comment: I am extremely @IVOGELOV. I did not see your  answer.I did not try. let me try :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date-fns` for this.

Example:

```
    import { isValid } from 'date-fns/isValid';
    import { isPast } from 'date-fns/isPast';
    import { isTomorrow } from 'date-fns/isTomorrow';
    import { isToday } from 'date-fns/isToday';
    
    const groupByDates = (data) => {
        const overdue = [];
        const today = [];
        const tomorrow = [];
        const rest = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            const date = new Date(Data[i].dueDatetime);
            if (isValid(date)) {
                if (isToday(date)) {
                    today.push(date);
                    continue;
                }
                if (isTomorrow(date)) {
                    tomorrow.push(date);
                    continue;
                }
                if (isPast(date)) {
                    overdue.push(date);
                    continue;
                }
                rest.push(date);
            }
        }
        return { overdue, today, tomorrow, rest };
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Arun. But I don't want to use any package,

Comment: @kisna if you what you can take a look complete solution here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/date-forked-exku6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: For the record. I did not do thumbs down. I really appreciate your answer